# Problems with drop down color changer

Tags: javascript, html

Hey i started learning JS today and i thought of trying to make a drop down color changer , i have tried many things but i cant seem to get it to work, i also tried onchange instead of onclick but still nothing , any help appreciated

HTML:

```
<label for="color">Choose a color: </label>
<select id="text" name="colorpicker">
    <option value="red" onclick="red()">Red</option>
    <option value="green" onclick="green()">Green</option>
    <option value="blue" onclick="blue()">Blue</option>
    <option value="purple" onclick="purple()">Purple</option>
</select>

<p id="text">This text changes color</p>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function red() {
    console.log((document.getElementById("text").style.color = "red"));
}
function green() {
    console.log((document.getElementById("text").style.color = "green"));
}
function blue() {
    console.log((document.getElementById("text").style.color = "blue"));
}
function purple() {
    console.log((document.getElementById("text").style.color = "purple"));
}
```

Comment: You need an onchange event for the select, and you need to look into how to get the value of a select field as part of that event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you use identifier **text** twice for different elements. Attribute **id** is a unique attribute, so I specified a different **id** for the `<select>` tag.

Second, I used event `onchange` for the `<select>` tag instead of the `onclick` event for the `<option>` tags, because this way is **correct**.

Third, a single function using the argument `element` is enough to assign a color. And to assign a color, we use the value of attribute `value` of the `<option>` tag. So you can add a new option tag with the desired color.

```js
function color(element) {
    document.getElementById("text").style.color = element.value;
}
```

```html
<label for="color">Choose a color: </label>
<select id="text_select" onchange="color(this)" name="colorpicker">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="purple">Purple</option>
</select>

<p id="text">This text changes color</p>
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works or what to search in order to learn this thanks!

Comment: @MGR, I have edited my reply with the explanation above.

Answer (score 0):

Press `f12` on your browser or go to settings -> dev tools(some like this..) and go to console from the menu (Inspector|Style|**Console** and read the error and copy it to here.

I tried your code block at another place and it returned an error. Please share the error message. And for future works search in the net for "your error message at console e.g. (ReferenceError: *error message text*), have a nice work.

You cannot give the same id to another element on the page. Try learning JS in depth by reading or watching videos.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).